# Merge tag vs2017 into visual-studio-2017

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The [vs2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2017) tag has over 100 questions. It should be merged into [visual-studio-2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) (2500+ questions). This will also make it consistent with previous versions of VS, which use `visual-studio-[year]` tags.

Comment: Why do i feel like this meta post happens once every Visual Studio release.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Because Stack Overlow Inc. doesn't care about this enough to actually make the tag synonyms feature work.

Comment: Done. Merged and syn'd.

Comment: s/Stack Overlow Inc/The Powers That Be/ much more ominous.